# iOS: align two UILabels' leading and trailing

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I need to align two `UILabel`'s leading and trailing, for example, I want the two labels to align like this (square brackets indicate the labels' frames):

```
label1 =      [Hello World in Big Font]
label2 =      [welcome to the world in
               smaller font that wraps
               into two multiple lines]
```

However the result is

```
label1 =      [                          Hello World in Big Font                      ]
label2 =      [welcome to the world in smaller font that wraps into two multiple lines]
```

I know I can tweak the preferred font width for the second label, but is there a better way around?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you upload the visual image for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the content hugging priority to `.defaultHigh + 1.0` for the first label.

Answer (score 0):

Add a width constraint for the second label to be equal to the width of the first label.

Comment: Thanks, let me try; But from the sound of it, it still could result in the unexpected behaviour which also satisfies that their width are equal. Updated: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
label1.text = "your text"
label1.sizeToFit()

label2.frame.size = label1.frame.size
label2.numberOfLines = 0
label2.text = "your long text"
```

Comment: Setting their frames would work, but I'm using auto-layout so I don't want to mess with frames...

Answer (score 0):

It's easy for [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)

```
label1.textAlignment = .left
self.view.addSubview(label1)
label1.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.height.left.top.equalTo(21)
    make.right. lessThanOrEqualTo(self.view).offset(-20)
}
label2.textAlignment = .left
label2.numberOfLines = 0
self.view.addSubview(label2)
label2.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.left.right.equalTo(label1)
    make.top.equalTo(label1.snp.bottom).offset(20)
}
```

Use AutoLayout Without SnapKit

```
        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.textAlignment = .left
        self.view.addSubview(label1)
        let constraintOne = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: label1, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let constraintTwo = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: label1, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
        let constraintThree = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: label1, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let constraintFour = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: label1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.textAlignment = .left
        label2.numberOfLines = 0
        self.view.addSubview(label2)
        let layoutConstraintOne = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: label2, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label1, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let layoutConstraintTwo = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: label2, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label1, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let layoutConstraintThree = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: label2, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label1, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraintOne, constraintTwo, constraintThree, constraintFour,layoutConstraintOne, layoutConstraintTwo,layoutConstraintThree ])
```

Comment: How about without `SnapKit`?

Answer (score 0):

For first label you can apply top and leading constraint only. So for second label, set leading, width same as first label.

Comment: thanks let me try, but I assume it would be similar, because it can also satisfy the constraint by making the 1st label to have same width as the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few approaches, I found a way to do it.

Instead of having constraint for label's leading and trailing, I make them all center X w.r.t superview, and in view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
[label1 sizeToFit]
```

which makes sure the `frame` of `label1` is just enough for its text, and then I do:

```
label2.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label1.bounds.size.width
```

and it's stated that `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`

> The preferred maximum width (in points) for a multiline label.
>
> This property affects the size of the label when layout constraints are applied to it. During layout, if the text extends beyond the width specified by this property, the additional text flows to one or more new lines, increasing the height of the label.

Which makes sure `label2`'text fits the width boundary of `label1`, and broken into multiple lines if the width isn't enough for single line text.